# What is the Sitecore Horizon 9.3 default style sheet and how can it be updated?

Tags: horizon

On the Sitecore Horizon 9.3 "On-premise Installation guide" it says to update the default stylesheet.

1. Which one is the default stylesheet?
2. How can we update it?

I did update the "horizon.xpsinglesc.dev.local\sitecore\Horizon.Client\Horizon.Client\dist\assets\css/index.css" 
However it dit not work.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Horizon when you try to use alignment and indentation feature, it basically adds the `.rte-indent-*` (where * is 1-8), `rte-align-justify`, `.rte-align-center` and `.rte-align-right` classes to the selected section. The Style will only work if you have the above CSS style(in your question) in your default CSS file. Here default CSS file is your website's default CSS (generally main.css) file which is used to style your website, not the horizon one.